# How to add a .ts file in html document via script and make it work

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a angular application, how do i add a typescript file in an html document, because i am getting an error which is :-"because its MIME type ('video/mp2t') is not executable."

Can typescript not be run directly, do they have to always be compiled into js to run in browser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

html script tag do not support typescript, you should compile ts to js,then use the compiled js file;

Comment: you should read this book to know how to use Typescript：https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/basic-types.html